# Sharing stories, test plans and updates between our devops instance and clients devops instance

Tags: azure, azure-devops, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

i'm wondering if anyone has had a similar requirement to this:

1. A client has a stream of work. They generate user stories in a project. Some are assigned to us as development projects.
2. We add the General user story to our dev ops, then generate more user stories, do the development and create test plans, etc.
3. We hand the work back over to the client and the test.

They do not want to be a stake holder in our devops, they have other work inside their devops that their users want to access.

We dont want to be a stakehodler in their teanancy as we expand ont eh user stories, add taks, link code and commits to the user stories.

What we would like to do is update each others project via power automate or custom code. Tehy want to send us the initial user stories. We want to send discussions to their user tory, as well as test plans and new user stories.

Anyone achieved this except with import/Export to excel?

i know it's a slightly strange scenario as we're managing smaller chunks of a larger project for them.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are tools like [TaskTop](https://www.tasktop.com/) and [OpsHub](https://www.opshub.com/products/opshub-integration-manager/) that enable syncing and conflict resolving changes between tools like Azure DevOps. They tend to be relatively expensive. But are feature rich and can resolve most issues.

You could use the [Azure DevOps Sync/Migration tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) to automatically sync changes from one Azure DevOps to another. It's a free solution, but can be complex to setup.

I'd urge not to rely on custom API solutions, since there are many strange conditions to take into account.

Answer (score 0):

You could check [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) and [Work Items - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) REST apis of Azure DevOps and customize your own solution:

**Work Items - Create sample:**

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/${type}?api-version=6.0

[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "from": null,
    "value": "Sample task"
  }
]
```

**Work Items - Update sample:**

```
PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.0

[
  {
    "op": "test",
    "path": "/rev",
    "value": 1
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.AreaPath",
    "value": "Fabrikam-Fiber-Git\\Website"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.History",
    "value": "Moving to the right area path"
  }
]
```

Comment: thanks, we'll have a look at the existing products before looking at custom code, but this is a help!